# Python: get index of row based on position

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my pandas dataframe

```
In [7]:  
dframe = pd.DataFrame({"A":list("abcde"), "B":list("fghij")}, index=[10,11,12,13,14])
dframe

Out[7]:
    A   B
10  a   f
11  b   g
12  c   h
13  d   i
14  e   j
```

Question 1:
How to get index of the third row? Answer is 12 
Question 2:
How to delete the third row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscript directly into the index attribute of the df, and pass this to [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to remove that specific row:

```
In [98]:
dframe.index[2]

Out[98]:
12
```

The above shows that the `index` object which is array like supports subscripting directly using integer based positioning.

```
In [99]:
dframe.drop(dframe.index[2])

Out[99]:
    A  B
10  a  f
11  b  g
13  d  i
14  e  j
```

Answer (score 0):

indexing:

```
In [158]: dframe.iloc[2]
Out[158]:
A    c
B    h
Name: 12, dtype: object
```

or

```
In [159]: dframe.iloc[[2]]
Out[159]:
    A  B
12  c  h
```

Comment: Thanks! But I just want an integer 12